# Accessing child array by index and updating view when index increments

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been working on a sample Knockout.js application where there is a list of offices and each office is associated with 1 or more sets of opening hours.

When I click on select in the table the opening hours are shown underneath for the first set of opening hours.

I want to be able to cycle through the array by clicking on the button to show the opening hours for Rota A, then B, then C and back to Rota A again.

With my current solution, if I press on the >> button currently the index is incremented but the opening hours table is not updated until I re-press the select button.

The jsfiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/58p57dv3/

How, do I make the opening hours in the table update automatically when I press the >>> button

**HTML**

```
  <div id="container">
        <div id="officeInfo">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Office ID</th>
                        <th>Office Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: offices">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: OfficeID"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: OfficeName"></td>
                        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.selectOffice">Select</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="openingHours" data-bind="with: selectedOffice">
            <input type="button" value=">>>" data-bind="click: $parent.nextOpeningHourType">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>Opening Time</th>
                        <th>Closing Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="with: OpeningHours()[$parent.index]">
                    <tr><td>Monday</td><td data-bind="text: MondayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: MondayEndTime"></tr>
                    <tr><td>Tueday</td><td data-bind="text: TuesdayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: TuesdayEndTime"></tr>
                    <tr><td>Wednesday</td><td data-bind="text: WednesdayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: WednesdayEndTime"></tr>
                    <tr><td>Thursday</td><td data-bind="text: ThursdayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: ThursdayEndTime"></tr>
                    <tr><td>Friday</td><td data-bind="text: FridayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: FridayEndTime"></tr>
                    <tr><td>Saturday</td><td data-bind="text: SaturdayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: SaturdayEndTime"></tr>
                    <tr><td>Sunday</td><td data-bind="text: SundayStartTime"></td><td data-bind="text: SundayEndTime"></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
var OfficeViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.offices = officeList;

    self.selectedOffice = ko.observable();
    self.index = ko.observable();
    self.index = 0;

    self.nextOpeningHourType = function() {
        if (self.index < 2) {
            self.index++;
        } else {
            self.index = 0;
        }
    }

    self.selectOffice = function (office) {
        self.selectedOffice(office);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it will work fine if you just make `index` an observable

```
self.index = ko.observable(0);
self.nextOpeningHourType = function() {
    if (self.index() < 2) {
        self.index(self.index()+1);
    } else {
        self.index(0);
    }
}

self.selectOffice = function (office) {
    self.index(0);
    self.selectedOffice(office);
}
```

and change your markup as

```
<tbody data-bind="with: OpeningHours()[$parent.index()]">
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/58p57dv3/2/